# Integrate gulp-livereload with Watchify

Tags: node.js, browserify, livereload, gulp

I'm using Substack's Watchify for better Browserify builds, within a Gulp watch task, like so:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watchify = require('watchify');

var hbsfy = require("hbsfy").configure({
  extensions: ["html"]
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    var bundler = watchify('./public/js/app.js');

    bundler.transform(hbsfy);

    bundler.on('update', rebundle);

    function rebundle() {
        return bundler.bundle()
            .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist/js/'));
    }

    return rebundle();
});
```

Trying to figure out how I can incorporate Live Reload into the task, so it triggers when Watchify has done it's thing. Any idea how I would do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using [`gulp-livereload`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-livereload) right after your `gulp.dest()`?

You should be able simply insert this:

```
.pipe(livereload())
```

This assumes that `bundler.bundle()` pipes the correct data types.

Comment: [vinyl-source-stream](https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-source-stream) (`.pipe(source('bundle.js'))` in his code) takes the text stream piped out from `bundler.bundle()` and makes it the vinyl file stream that gulp uses, replacing `gulp.src()`. Thus other gulp plugins can be piped after that.

Comment: Note also, that if you're using gulp-connect, you can `.pipe(connect.reload())`

Comment: I found, `.pipe(livereload())` is not enough, you have to add `.pipe(livereload({start: true}))` or the LiveReload server will not be started (obviously you can also start the server somewhere else in your script). Having to start the listener seems to be a change since 3.x